# Analyse code for spatial and temporal locality

Tags: spatial, cpu-architecture, temporal

Hi have some question regarding spatial and temporal locality. I have read in the course theory that

### spatial locality

If one item is referenced, the likelihood of other address close by will be referenced soon

### temporal locality

One item that is referenced at one point in time it tend to be referenced soon again.

Ok, but how do I see that in the code? I think I understood the concept for temporal locality but I don't understand spatial locality yet. For instance in this loop

```
for(i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        a[i] = a[i]*j;
```

The inner loop will call same memory address when accessing a[i] ten times so that's an example for temporal locality I guess. But is there spatial locality also in the above loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course. For instance, after referencing a[5] you are about to reference a[6].