# Defining locality in pseudocode

Tags: cpu-architecture

I'm trying to figure out which locality (spatial/temporal) is used in the following pseudo code and how?

```
for i = 0, i < 10, i++ 
    sum = sum + array[i]
```

I hope my question is clear and somebody could help me, thanks in advance! 
Steven

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spatial vs. Temporal locality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264767/spatial-vs-temporal-locality)

Comment: sorry, my bad, but could you explain me if the code is making use of temporal locality? assuming "sum" is used 10 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, given the code-snippet, one can't just determine easily about spatial locality unless the whole code is given.

**`Temporal Locality`** refers to the reuse of specific data, and/or resources, within a relatively small time duration..

Whereas, **`Spatial Locality`**  refers to the use of data elements within relatively close storage locations.

Next, considering this snippet, as `sum` is to be called 10 times in 10 iterations of i, hence, repetitive reference to `sum` depicts temporal locality.