# Why does cache locality matter for array performance?

Tags: arrays, language-agnostic, linked-list

In the following [blog](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/10245) there is a statement about the advantage of arrays over linked lists:

> Arrays have better cache locality that can make a pretty big difference in performance.

What does that mean? I don't understand how cache locality can provide a huge performance benefit.

Comment: If you understand how [cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) works, then you'll also understand 1) "Locality of Reference" is a Good Thing, and 2) accessing data from arrays is usually more likely to have good "locality" than accessing the same data from a list.

Comment: One thing worth noting is that while this is true, a singly-linked list combined with a contiguous allocator can be an enormous asset, mainly because transferring elements from one container to another just involves pointer logic. If you look at the memory layout of those, however, it's contiguous and looks like an array with just links to the next element in the array, and so it's still cache-friendly (at least until the list is all reorganized).

Answer (score 155, accepted):

See my answer [about spatial and temporal locality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7812002/950912).

In particular, arrays are contiguous memory blocks, so large chunks of them will be loaded into the cache upon first access.  This makes it comparatively quick to access future elements of the array.  Linked lists on the other hand aren't necessarily in contiguous blocks of memory, and could lead to more cache misses, which increases the time it takes to access them.

Consider the following possible memory layouts for an array `data` and linked list `l_data` of large structs

```
Address      Contents       | Address      Contents
ffff 0000    data[0]        | ffff 1000    l_data
ffff 0040    data[1]        |   ....
ffff 0080    data[2]        | ffff 3460    l_data->next
ffff 00c0    data[3]        |   ....
ffff 0100    data[4]        | ffff 8dc0    l_data->next->next
                            | ffff 8e00    l_data->next->next->next
                            |   ....
                            | ffff 8f00    l_data->next->next->next->next
```

If we wanted to loop through this array, the first access to `ffff 0000` would require us to go to memory to retrieve (a very slow operation in CPU cycles).  However, after the first access the rest of the array would be in the cache, and subsequent accesses would be much quicker.  With the linked list, the first access to `ffff 1000` would also require us to go to memory.  Unfortunately, the processor will cache the memory directly surrounding this location, say all the way up to `ffff 2000`.  As you can see, this doesn't actually capture any of the other elements of the list, which means that when we go to access `l_data->next`, we will again have to go to memory.

Comment: Note that the locality of linked lists can be improved through use of a memory pool.  But you still have the issue that 'next' pointers take up extra space.

Comment: @paddy makes a good point because frequently this is how linked lists are implemented

Comment: Now i got what "Cache misses in Linked list" means.

Comment: So is the locality of reference of Linked lists spatial or temporal or both or none?

Answer (score 18):

Typically, when using an array you access items that are near each other.  This is especially true when accessing an array sequentially.

When you access memory, a chunks of it are cached at various levels.  *Cache locality* refers to the likelihood of successive operations being in the cache and thus being faster.  In an array, you maximize the chances of sequential element access being in the cache.

With lists, by counter-example, there's no guarantee that items which appear sequentially in the list are actually arranged near eachother in memory.  This means fewer cache hits, and degraded performance.

Comment: This depends very much on the processor and the memory architecture, however. CPUs which are designed for object-oriented programming, for example, usually don't care about locality, simply because by the very *definition* of "object-oriented" you cannot guarantee locality anyway.

Comment: @JörgWMittag So do you mean to say that programs written in OOP languages don't use the caches effectively, or there are more cache misses in that case as compared to a program written in a procedural language?

Comment: @SaurabhPatil In OO you generally have an array of objects. if you have to access one property of each object, the CPU loads quite a number of unrelevant data that also belong to the objects. see this link for more explaination. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AoS_and_SoA

Comment: Well, not only this, but objects will typically be allocated dynamically.  Even with the most intelligent memory allocator in the world that might result in objects being packed together, or if you allocate then as an array, because some part of the object must refer to a class then by design you will lose some memory to that metadata.  In C++ this is the virtual table, stored inside the object.  Other OO languages may use a different scheme but you will end up either spacing your objects' data in memory, or storing some lookup table elsewhere: either of which would impact locality.