# what is the difference between linear array and multi-dimensional?

Tags: c++, arrays

Arrays can be linear (one dimension) or multi-dimensional. What is the difference between these arrays as long as they give the same result?

I think an array is a set of consecutive addresses of the same type and size in memory. Is this applicable to multi-dimensional array?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{

    int array1[4]       = {0, 1, 2, 3};
    int array2[1][4]    = {0, 1, 2, 3};
    int array3[1][2][2] = {0, 1, 2, 3};

    cout << array1[0]       << endl; // 0
    cout << array2[0][0]    << endl; // 0
    cout << array3[0][0][0] << endl; // 0

    cout << array1[2]       << endl; // 2
    cout << array2[0][2]    << endl; // 2
    cout << array3[0][1][0] << endl; // 2

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the difference is the way the elements are accessed. If you need a 3d structure you dont want to write `array3[ i + size_i * j + size_i * size_j * k]` but you want to write `array3[i][j][k]`

Comment: @tobi303 That's perhaps a little disingenuous because of potential benefits from spacial locality.

Comment: @erip not sure if I understand your comment.....

Comment: A 2D array, is an array of arrays. It's elements are consecutive arrays. A 3D array, is an array of 2D arrays. It's elements are consecutive 2D arrays. And so forth. So I believe your intuition is correct. You should note that initializing all the arrays the same, is syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multidimensional arrays can be *represented* one of at least two ways: a single 1x(N*M) array, or as N number of 1xM arrays (which are consecutive in memory, as well). To fit with your nomenclature, we'll call the former a linear array and the latter a "multidimensional" array.

Languages which are *row order* (like C++) benefit greatly from cache coherence (due to spacial locality) when arrays are stored linearly. When iterating over columns, you'll find your cache misses much more frequently.

This is obviously a function of the size of your caches and how often you think you'll be iterating over the matrices, so make sure it's a bottleneck before making huge design decisions.

For more information, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722520/why-is-iterating-2d-array-row-major-faster-than-column-major) and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order).

Answer (score 1):

It is just syntactic sugar. You could declare a plain int as `int x;` or as `int x[1][1][1][1][1];`. It won't affect memory layout, but the latter form is very inconvenient to use, when all you need is a single integer.

Similarly, when working with data that should represent 2 dimensions, it is inconvenient to work with a single "mangled" array that you have to access through `[i*YSIZE + j]` rather than `[i][j]`.

Answer (score 0):

Say I have to store **10** 1-dimensional arrays together. So what will you do?

Merge them into one large array?

That is one possible solution! **But Hell no!** What's more neat and readable solution? Make an array of those one dimensional array! Isn't it? That gives us a 2 dimensional array.

So that's what the importance of a multidimensional array even though you can access values in all types of arrays.

I hope you haven't started coding a lot now. Cause once you start coding the use of single dimension and multi dimension become more obvious rather than gathering knowledge from reading.

Comment: It isn't that hard to access values in a one-dimensionally represented matrix.