# C++ Fill a 2D vector with alternate values

Tags: c++, initialization, alternate, 2d-vector

I have a 2D vector vector of characters `grid[j][i]` filled with various letters, I would like to create another 2D vector of characters twice the size of `grid[j][i]` filled alternately with points `'.'`(or spaces `' '`) and `grid[j][i]` values.

For example :

```
      grid                    new 2D vector       

    a b c d                   a . b . c . d        
    e f g h                   . . . . . . .
    i j k l                   e . f . g . h
                              . . . . . . .
                              i . j . k . l
```

**Does anyone have an idea of how to implement this in C++ using vectors ?**

Thanks in advance for any help you could provide.

Comment: Check out the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on dos and donts.

Comment: Show us what have you tried, what are you having difficulties with?

Answer (score 3):

Easy right? If the row or column number is a multiple of 2 (1 based counting) then you want a `.` or `' '` inserted.

Here is some psuedo code:

```
for each row
    if (row+1 mod 2)
        add a row of .
    else
        for each column
            if (col+1 mod 2)
               add .
            add grid[row][col]
```

and you are done!

Comment: Note that the order of the loops---row, column---is not best practice since C/C++ is row-major.

Comment: @Richard Can you elaborate? In a 2D vector in c++ the row/column order can be whatever i choose it to be?

Comment: @Richard According to [this wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) and [this  question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722520/why-is-iterating-2d-array-row-major-faster-than-column-major), this is the correct order to iterate for speed purposes.

Comment: My apologies, I had a temporary bout of dyslexia. I meant to come back and correct myself, but got distracted.