# If I have two functions copyij() and copyji(), to copy a 2048x2048 integer array, which one is faster and why?

Tags: c++, performance

This is in C++, and I used the time command on Unix and found that copyij() was significantly faster.

```
void copyij(long int src[MSize][MSize], long int dst[MSize][MSize])
{
  long int i,j;
  for (i = 0; i < MSize; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < MSize; j++)
      dst[i][j] = src[i][j];
}
```

copyji() is similar, except the j loop is before the i-loop.

Comment: What compilation flags did you use? Especially the optimizing ones?

Comment: And an even faster method:  `memcpy(&dst[0][0], &src[0][0], sizeof(long) * MSize * MSize);`

Comment: Probably because the first one works better with [caching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache).

Comment: If you timed them, why are you asking which is faster?

Comment: Related: [Why is iterating 2D array row major faster than column major?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722520/why-is-iterating-2d-array-row-major-faster-than-column-major)